# cq:showOnCreate not working with RTE on Page properties

Tags: aem

We are using an RTE field in the page properties. The issue here is, this field doesn't render in the page properties when author is creating the page. Is this a known issue with AEM? Is there any workaround for this?

```
 <bannerText
    cq:showOnCreate="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
    fieldLabel="Banner text"
    fieldDescription="This text describes the banner message."
    required="true"
    name="./bannerText"
    useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
<rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <format
....
<bannerText?>
```

PS: We are using AEM 6.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a limitation.  RTE capabilities are supported only in AEM component dialogs. RTE is not supported on wizards or Foundation-forms like Page Properties and Scaffolding on Touch-enabled UI.                                                                                                             
FYI-https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/administering/operations/rich-text-editor.html#known-limitations